# How to filter out letters from numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that calculates the area of a trapezoid, and rejects letters until the user inputs a number but it throws an error at the bottom when I input all the values.

```
    print("Enter 'x' to exit.")
    starter = input("Press any key except 'x' to continue: ")
    if starter == 'x':
        break
    else:
        print("\nCalculating area of a trapezoid")
        base_1 = 5
        base_2 = 6
        height = input('Height of Trapezoid: ')
        while not height.isdigit():
            height = input("Error. Please input height as a positive number: ")

        base_1 = input('Base one value: ')
        while not base_1.isdigit():
            base_1 = input("Error. Please input base one as a positive number: ")

        base_2 = input('Base two value: ')
        while not base_2.isdigit():
            base_2 = input("Error. Please input base two as a positive number: ")

        print("the area of the trapezoid is: " + str(area = ((base_1 +base_2)/2)*height))
```

Typical error I receive.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\$College Class Notes\Python\First Project.py", line 78, in <module>
    print("the area of the trapezoid is: " + str(area = ((base_1 +base_2)/2)*height))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the user is are inputing numbers, `input()` returns a string. You'll need to cast them to ints yourself.

```
    base_1 = input('Base one value: ')
    while not base_2.isdigit():
        base_1 = input("Error. Please input base one as a positive number: ")
    base_1 = int(base_1)
```

Also, no need to set `area = ((....))` in your print statement. That is actually invalid syntax. You could just remove the `area =` and it will work, but to make the code cleaner, I'd move your `area` assignment outside of the print.

```
area = ((base_1 +base_2)/2)*height
print("the area of the trapezoid is: " + str(area))
```

In order to get floats, I'd just put it in a try/catch. You can set the while condition to whether base_1 is set or not since if an exception is raised, base_1 still won't be set.

```
base_1 = None
while not base_1:
    try:
        base_1 = float(input('Please input a number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Error. Not a number')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That worked, and now it prints an answer that is incorrect when I compare it to math myself.  Is there any way I can get it to accept decimals as well or will that make the code much more complicated. Thanks!

Comment: Correction, formula works correctly. Just wondering if I can allow it to accept digits. Thanks!

Comment: @CupOfKoffee I updated my answer to accept floats without complicating the code too much.